# Change div id text content

Tags: javascript, html

so i've been trying to change the text in a div.

```
<div id="company">
<div id="companyname">some name</div>
</div>
```

I thought a simple:

```
document.getElementById("companyname").innerText = "Company";
```

Would work, but no.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: would you add this part of DOM?

Comment: Where do you run that JS from?

Comment: tyr this document.getElementById("companyname").innerHTML = "Company";

Comment: Try to replace `innerText` by `innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make sure you are appending content when Document is loaded
>   completely.

Try to put it in :

```
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("companyname").innerText = "Company"; };
```

Or Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#companyname').html('company');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("companyname").innerHTML  = 'teste';
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div id="companyname"><div>
  </body>
</html>
```